# How can I say "Right now it is lunch time so it's very quiet"?

Tags: grammar

Is it "ima ha hiruyasumi Kara totemo shizuka desu." Or is something off? I have to do a video project in Japanese for Japanese class.

Answer (score 1):

kara→dakara

"ima ha hiruyasumi dakara totemo shizuka desu."